# How does the built-in map() function affect itemgetter() and database cursors? - Python

Tags: python, map-function, database-cursor

In Python 2.7, using `MySQLdb` package, I cannot understand following behaviours of `itemgetter()` and database cursor's `execute()` function:

```
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT 1+2')  # could be any other valid query
map(itemgetter(0), c)
```

which will return a list `[3]`.

But either `itemgetter(0)(c)` or `c[0]` gives an `TypeError` saying 'Cursor' object does not support indexing, which is totally understandable.

How can `map()` and `itemgetter()` retrieve the result of a query from a 
 database cursor **before** the cursor calls `fetchone` or `fetchall` method?

Comment: The answer to this question is basically the same as the answer to "How is a generator different from a list." Compare `a = range(3); a[3]` with `b = iter(range(3)); b[3]`, but `map(lambda x: x*2, a)` works as well as `map(lambda x: x*2, b)` (while `(lambda x: x*2)(a)` and `(lambda x: x*2)(b)` fail, as does `b[3]`)

Comment: @Yician, thnx for the edit (in my dba.se answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the description of map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

> Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results.

According to [the description of iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable),

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as list, str, and tuple) and some non-sequence types like dict and file and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, ...).

Therefore, the iterable must define either `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()`.

From [the source of MySQLdb](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/mysqldb-2/ci/default/tree/MySQLdb/cursors.py#l317),  the cursor object defines `__iter__()` but not `__getitem__()`

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.fetchone, None)
```

Since it does not define `__getitem__()`, nither `itemgetter(0)(c)` nor `c[0]` works.
However, since it defines `__iter__()`, you can use `map()` item to get each item which is the result of `self.fetchone`.

Therefore the `itemgetter(0)` is actually applied to result of `self.fetchone()` which is row object.
Row object seems to be just an list object, so you can apply `itemgetter(0)(row)` which returns `row[0]`